# Sorting javascript array foreach

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, foreach, integer

I am new to programming. Can someone explain how is this function sorting integer array? It appears to be sorting an array. What is the purpose of creating array "d" here?

```js
function asc(f) {

  var d = [];
  f.map(function(e, i, a) {
    d[i] = e
  })
  var k = [];
  f.forEach(function(e, i, a) {
    var g = d.indexOf(Math.min.apply(null, d))
    var s = d.splice(g, 1)
    k[i] = s
  })

  document.write(k)
}
asc([3, 4, 1, 2, -3, 20, 10, 22, 7, 5, 7, 8, 200, 6])
```

Comment: It’s creating an empty array which is then populated with values in the .map function. Essentially it’s creating a copy of the input array `f`.

Comment: To learn things better print the data inside the map function, foreach etc. You can see how the data is getting transformed and will better understand the purpose of each of them.

Answer (score 4):

The array `d` is an exact copy of the original array.
The code uses this copy because intentionally removes the minimum element on each itteration and stores it in the new `k` array which is the final sorted array. I have made comments in the code to show you what each line does.

```js
function asc(f) {
  //f is the original array
  var d = [];
  f.map(function(e, i, a) {
    d[i] = e
  })// create d as an exact copy of f
  
  var k = []; // the final sorted array
  f.forEach(function(e, i, a) {
    var g = d.indexOf(Math.min.apply(null, d)) // get the position of the minimum element of d
    var s = d.splice(g, 1) // remove the minimum element from d and store it in s
    k[i] = s // put s in the k array
  })

  document.write(k) // write the sorted array in document
}
asc([3, 4, 1, 2, -3, 20, 10, 22, 7, 5, 7, 8, 200, 6])
```

Ofcourse there is a better way to sort an array using the builtin [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function.

```js
[3, 4, 1, 2, -3, 20, 10, 22, 7, 5, 7, 8, 200, 6].sort(function(a,b){
  return a-b  
})
```